# Cant set default dark theme in Eclipse RCP pure e4 - @import url seems to not import color definitions or they are overriden

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I cant set dark theme in my pure e4 application. Theme is partially changed to dark but MPart -> TabItems are still in the bright color. I downloaded the latest Eclipse IDE + latest releases of e4 packages. In the /css/default.css I added one line:

```
@import url("platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui.themes/css/e4-dark.css");
```

and in the plugin.xml,

```
applicationCSS: platform:/plugin/PackMe/css/default.css
```

Somewhere on the beginning of the file e4-dark.css there are 3 external css imports with color definitions (e4-dark_basestyle.css etc) and it seems like the imports are not working or they are somehow overriden as I tried to hardcode one color in CSS e4-dark and it works:

```
    swt-selected-tab-fill: '#FF0000' '#org-eclipse-ui-workbench-INACTIVE_TAB_BG_END' 100%; /* title background for selected tab */
```

Parts are being created using Application.e4xmi
I would expect to have the same cool dark theme as it is in the Eclipse IDE -> dark theme (and as I checked in the exported product there is the same version of Eclipse IDE and my product: org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.200)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing referencing `org.eclipse.ui.xxxx` is part of pure e4.

The `org.eclipse.ui.themes` plug-in is not part of pure e4.

The `#org-eclipse-ui-workbench-INACTIVE_TAB_BG_END` method of defining colors is not part of pure e4.

You will have to write the CSS styles yourself. You could use the CSS from org.eclipse.ui.themes as a base but you would have to replace all the org.eclipse.ui.xxx values.

Comment: but it seems like the CSS attributes are the same, the problem seems to be only with color-definition and/or @import url or anything that overrides some definitions

Comment: Things like  `org-eclipse-ui-workbench-INACTIVE_TAB_BG_END` are defined in the 3.x compatibility mode code, they have no value in pure e4. You could use the CSS from `org.eclipse.ui.themes` as a base but you would have to replace all the org.eclipse.ui.xxx values

Answer (score 0):

As @greg-449 points out, the `org.eclipse.ui.themes` is **not** part of e4 - even though the CSS files have the prefix "e4-" and the bundle has no further dependencies. That is a pity because the symbolic names for colors (for example `org-eclipse-ui-workbench-INACTIVE_TAB_BG_END`) are actually also defined in the CSS files (as `ColorDefinition#org-eclipse-ui-workbench-INACTIVE_TAB_BG_END`).

In order **to use the CSS files**, you have to create some glue code:

- Whenever a theme is selected, extract the color and font definitions by styling a `ThemesExtension`, `ColorDefinition`, and `FontDefinition` objects
- Register a `IColorAndFontProvider` service that is called to resolve colors and fonts and return the definitions extracted above

Roughly it looks like this:

**Register a Service Component in your Manifest.mf**

```
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/custom.e4app.ColorAndFontProviderImpl.xml
```

**The OSGi service descriptor**

Listen to `themeChanged` event and provide colors and fonts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="name.abuchen.portfolio.ui.util.theme.ColorAndFontProviderImpl">
    <property name="event.topics" value="org/eclipse/e4/ui/css/swt/theme/ThemeManager/themeChanged"/>
    <service>
        <provide interface="org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.css.swt.definition.IColorAndFontProvider"/>
        <provide interface="org.osgi.service.event.EventHandler"/>
    </service>
    <implementation class="custom.e4app.ColorAndFontProviderImpl"/>
 </scr:component>
```

**Extract color definitions and implement color provider**

```
@Component(property = EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC + "=" + IThemeEngine.Events.THEME_CHANGED)
public class ColorAndFontProviderImpl implements IColorAndFontProvider, EventHandler
{
    private Map<String, RGB> colors = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event)
    {
        IThemeEngine engine = (IThemeEngine) event.getProperty(IThemeEngine.Events.THEME_ENGINE);

        ThemesExtension extension = new ThemesExtension();
        engine.applyStyles(extension, false);

        colors.clear();

        // add colors not defined in the CSS files

        colors.put("org.eclipse.ui.workbench.ACTIVE_TAB_BG_START",
                        Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_BACKGROUND).getRGB());

        colors.put("org.eclipse.ui.workbench.ACTIVE_TAB_BG_END",
                        Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BACKGROUND).getRGB());

        colors.put("org.eclipse.ui.workbench.ACTIVE_TAB_TEXT_COLOR",
                        Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_TITLE_FOREGROUND).getRGB());

        colors.put("org.eclipse.ui.workbench.INACTIVE_TAB_TEXT_COLOR",
                        Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_FOREGROUND).getRGB());

        for (String symbolicName : extension.getColors())
        {
            ColorDefinition definition = new ColorDefinition(symbolicName);
            engine.applyStyles(definition, false);
            colors.put(symbolicName, definition.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public FontData[] getFont(String symbolicName)
    {
        // same for fonts...
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public RGB getColor(String symbolicName)
    {
        return colors.computeIfAbsent(symbolicName, name -> new RGB(0, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

**Register element handler so that your custom ThemesExtension and ColorDefinition is styled**

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.elementProvider">
    <provider class="custom.e4app.ThemeElementDefinitionProvider">
        <widget class="custom.e4app.ThemesExtension"></widget>
        <widget class="custom.e4app.ColorDefinition"></widget>
    </provider>
</extension>
```

with

```
public class ThemeElementDefinitionProvider implements IElementProvider {
    @Override
    public Element getElement(Object element, CSSEngine engine) {
        if (element instanceof IFontDefinitionOverridable) {
            return new FontDefinitionElement((IFontDefinitionOverridable) element, engine);
        }
        if (element instanceof IColorDefinitionOverridable) {
            return new ColorDefinitionElement((IColorDefinitionOverridable) element, engine);
        }
        if (element instanceof IThemesExtension) {
            return new ThemesExtensionElement((IThemesExtension) element, engine);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ThemesExtension implements IThemesExtension
{
    List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void addColorDefinition(String symbolicName)
    {
        colors.add(symbolicName);
    }

    public List<String> getColors()
    {
        return colors;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class ColorDefinition implements IColorDefinitionOverridable
{
    private String id;
    private RGB value;

    public ColorDefinition(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(RGB data)
    {
        this.value = data;
    }

    @Override
    public RGB getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    ...
}
```